# how to make a validation in sharepoint online that accepts only alphabets?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, column-validation

I need sharepoint online column to accept only alphabets. It should not contain any numeric or special values.

Comment: Have you checked `PreSaveAction`? Can you add script editor webpart?

Comment: Yes, but (a)could find the save button to apply that code on to my list so i clicked on  web part properties and then applied it. (b) it does not work because when i open the list, the webpart appears on top of the list with code written in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharePoint Column Validation.

Edit the column and paste below formula in Column Validation Formula. You could even write the custom error message:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("1",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("2",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("3",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("4",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("5",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("6",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("7",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("8",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("9",Title)),TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exact same formula I used to make it work.